# Banshee podcasts episodes

Tags: banshee, podcast

Recently I have downloaded all the episodes of a podcast to Banshee. I can only see the first couple dozen of them in the player screen, yet if I look in the downloads folder or searched them in Banshee they are there.

How can I make Banshee show all of them in the browsing screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch between *All items* and *New Items* in the left top corner (over the list of all podcasts you are subscribed to).